# fprintf giving me a blank .txt file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have an intricate code in MATLAB that imports and runs an old fortran code.

The fortran code runs an electro-refining process and creates many output files of various data, but it only does it once.

Our goal was to have MATLAB run the program multiple times and for it to change the element concentration each time.

It does these things fine. Basically it takes the last line of values in our output file (element weight percents) and updates the input file with those values so that the next run will start where the last one left off.

The fortran code overrides the input and output file each time it is ran. This is a problem when trying to run multiple times without having to copy the file and rename it each time.

The MATLAB code does this:

```
% Step 1: Reading the data from the output file "outblk1" line by line.
    clear tline;
    fid = fopen('outblk1');
    tline{1}=fgetl(fid);
    cont=1;
    while ischar(tline{cont})
        cont = cont+1;
        tline{cont}=fgetl(fid);
    end
    fclose(fid);
    % Step 2: Rewriting the data presented in the output file "outblk1" in
    % the file "outblk1_step"
    fid = fopen( sprintf( 'outblk1_%i.txt',step), 'w');
    for i = 1:(numel(tline)-1)
        if tline{i+1} ==-1
            fprintf(fid, '%s', tline{i});
            break
        else
            fprintf(fid, '%s\n', tline{i});
        end
    end
    fclose(fid);
```

This works perfectly for the output files. Except for the first row which is headings everything is digits.

After the program is done, instead of 
outblk1

I get 
outblk1
outblk1.txt
outblk2.txt
etc

I want to do the same thing with the input file. After everything is finished all I have access to is the original input file (if I save a copy before running the program) and the last input file that was updated after the last output file was finished. I want each updated input file along the way. So I did this:

```
 % Reading the data from "inpref"
clear tline;
fid = fopen('inpref');
tline{1} =textscan(fid, '%s');
cont=1;
while ischar(tline{cont})
    cont = cont+1;
    tline{cont}=textscan(fid, '%s');
end
fclose(fid);
% Rewriting the data from "inpref" to "inpref_step"
fid = fopen( sprintf( 'inpref_%i.txt',step), 'w');
for i = 1:(numel(tline)-1)
    if tline{i+1} ==-1
        fprintf(fid, '%s', tline{i});
        break
    else
        fprintf(fid, '%s\n', tline{i});
    end
end
fclose(fid);
```

All I want is a copy of each updated input file.

inpref1.txt
inpref2.txt 
etc

Just like I get for the output files.

I originally tried it identically to the output version of the code with fget1 but it didn't work since there is a mix of data and numbers in the input file.

I also tried it like this:

```
% Reading the data from "inpref"
clear tline;
fid = fopen('inpref');
input =textscan(fid, '%s');
cont=1;
fclose(fid);
% Rewriting the data from "inpref" to "inpref_step"
fid = fopen( sprintf( 'inpref_%i.txt',step), 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', input);
fclose(fid);
```

but I get this error:

```
Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

Error in save_step_data (line 17)
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', input);
```

I have looked up MATLAB help info on fprintf, fopen, tline, fget, copyfile, textscan, and many other things branching off from there, but they all lead me to doing something with numbers. You wouldn't think it would be this hard to just make a copy of a file and have it sequence up so that you wouldn't have to stop and rename it each loop.

The sequencing works. I get the inpref1.txt, ..., the rest of the code works fine, this is one chunk of one file out of 10 or so that executes a fortran code that has 100 or more parts and it all comes out fine. The inpref file itself still updates properly with the new concentration data.

The only problem I have is that the .txt copies of the file are completely blank.

My other option is to go into the matlab code that updates the input file with the new concentrations and find a way to make a new file that just has concentration values in it that appends each time. I would also need the total mass for each run. Those are really the only 2 things that change in the whole input file. The salt concentrations in mass percent and the total mass of the salt.

Personally, I thought it would be easier just to make a copy of the input file each time it runs.

Comment: I feel a bit dirty for suggesting this, but could you get MATLAB to run a shell command with [`!`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/run-external-commands-scripts-and-programs.html) or [`system`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html)? For windows this would be something like `system(['copy inpref inpref_',num2str(step),'.txt'])`. Usual warnings apply, don't use `!` or `system` unless you know what they're going to do. (Maybe I've misunderstood what you're trying to do)

Comment: ! might be risky because the input file is full of ! because that is the equivalent of % to comment something out in MATLAB

Comment: This piece of the code is part of a subroutine that is called by another matlab file. The whole MATLAB code is basically a script that runs an old fortran program. It allows us to changed the variables without having to go through the 300 line input file. Then it runs the fortran program on a loop however many times we tell it to. The fortran code overrides the output file and input file each time so the code above makes a copy of the output file at each step. I want the same for the  input file, so if step 50 output shows a problem I can look at input file 50 and see what caused it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, rather than loading in and reading out the files, you can simply use `copyfile` to make a differently named copy. `movefile` would also work fine if the input file is overwritten rather than updated at each step, but if the fortran program expects to find `inpref` from the iteration each time it runs, then you should stick with `copyfile`.

e.g.

```
fname = sprintf('outblk1_%i.txt',step);
copyfile('outblk1', fname);
```

Comment: Great! That works. I had tried copyfile before but it didn't work how I intended. All it gave me was a file with the %i included. I also got it to work by changing the 'w' in the original code to 'w+' but I think copyfile will take a lot less time than the line by line way. Thanks!